# C# query only parent nodes of xslt

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xslt

I have below xslt :-

```
<IncidentTicket ExternalSystemName="{ExternalSystemName}" Company="$Company">
<xsl:if test="{Incident-LastResolvedDate} and {Incident-LastResolvedDate} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="LastResolvedDate">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-LastResolvedDate}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ServiceType} and {Incident-ServiceType} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ServiceType">
      <xsl:value-of select="'Incident'" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
<ExternalRelease>
<xsl:if test="incTest4 and incTest4 != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:attribute name="TestDate">
<xsl:value-of select="incTest4" />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
</ExternalRelease>
</IncidentTicket>
```

We can see there is node `<ExternalRelease>` within  node.

When I query  to search if attribute name "TestDate" exists or not , :-

```
var isAttributeAlreadyExists = result.Descendants().Attributes("name").Where(x => x.Value == "TestDate").Any();
```

This always returns me True as it is having it into ExternalRelease Node.

When I query , I dont want to use sub nodes like ExternalRelease , I want to check only within IncidentTicket.

How can I achieve this?

Result Content :-

```
<IncidentTicket ExternalSystemName="{ExternalSystemName}" Company="$Company">
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-LastResolvedDate} and {Incident-LastResolvedDate} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="LastResolvedDate">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-LastResolvedDate}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ServiceType} and {Incident-ServiceType} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ServiceType">
      <xsl:value-of select="'Incident'" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-IncidentNumber} and {Incident-IncidentNumber} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="IncidentNumber">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-IncidentNumber}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ReportedDateTime} and {Incident-ReportedDateTime} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ReportedDateTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-ReportedDateTime}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-LastModifiedTime} and {Incident-LastModifiedTime} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="LastModifiedTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-LastModifiedTime}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-Priority} and {Incident-Priority} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="Priority">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-Priority}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-Status} and {Incident-Status} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="Status">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-Status}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-TicketDescription} and {Incident-TicketDescription} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="TicketDescription">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-TicketDescription}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-AssigneeLoginId} and {Incident-AssigneeLoginId} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="AssigneeLoginId">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-AssigneeLoginId}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-DueDate} and {Incident-DueDate} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="DueDate">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-DueDate}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-SupportGroupName} and {Incident-SupportGroupName} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="SupportGroupName">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-SupportGroupName}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ResolutionDescription} and {Incident-ResolutionDescription} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ResolutionDescription">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-ResolutionDescription}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-Category} and {Incident-Category} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="Category">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-Category}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ClosedDate} and {Incident-ClosedDate} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ClosedDate">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-ClosedDate}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ReportedSource} and {Incident-ReportedSource} != 'null'" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ReportedSource">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-ReportedSource}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-CreatedBy} and {Incident-CreatedBy} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="CreatedBy">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-CreatedBy}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-LongDescription} and {Incident-LongDescription} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="LongDescription">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-LongDescription}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-CallerId} and {Incident-CallerId} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="CallerId">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-CallerId}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-Impact} and {Incident-Impact} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="Impact">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-Impact}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-Urgency} and {Incident-Urgency} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="Urgency">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-Urgency}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-CorrelationId} and {Incident-CorrelationId} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="CorrelationId">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-CorrelationId}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-RelatedIncidents} and {Incident-RelatedIncidents} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="RelatedIncidents">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-RelatedIncidents}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-RelatedProblems} and {Incident-RelatedProblems} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="RelatedProblems">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-RelatedProblems}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-RelatedTasks} and {Incident-RelatedTasks}!= ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="RelatedTasks">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-RelatedTasks}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ResponseDueDate} and {Incident-ResponseDueDate} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ResponseDueDate">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-ResponseDueDate}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ResolutionDueDate} and {Incident-ResolutionDueDate} != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ResolutionDueDate">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-ResolutionDueDate}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="{Incident-ConfigurationItem} and {Incident-ConfigurationItem}!= ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute name="ConfigurationItem">
      <xsl:value-of select="{Incident-ConfigurationItem}" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
                  {Incident-TestCondition}
                  {Attr-Incident}

                <ExternalRelease><xsl:if test="incTest4 and incTest4 != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:attribute name="TestDate"><xsl:value-of select="incTest4" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if></ExternalRelease></IncidentTicket>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Elements()` instead of `Descendants()`

Comment: result.Elements().Attributes("name").Where(x => x.Value == "TestDate").Any()  Every time this gives me false.. Even though element is present, it returns me false

Comment: Post result content

Comment: posted.. Please have a look at once

Comment: ExternalRelease node is not static , it can contain any name

Comment: Attribute Name= "TestDate"

Comment: There isn't any attribute with TestDate as value

Comment: <ExternalRelease><xsl:if test="incTest4 and incTest4 != ''" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:attribute name="TestDate"><xsl:value-of select="incTest4" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if></ExternalRelease>

Comment: Please look into last most part of xslt

Comment: But it isn't a direct child of the root, that's what you asked for

Comment: It should not consider the children while adding

Comment: I don't understand your sentences, what do you want this code to do?

Comment: If parent node is having "TestDate" attribute once (only parent node , not child node) then it should not allow me to add.. Once added "TestDate" in parent node, it should not allow me to repeatedly add again